# JQuery TokenInput

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jQuery tokeninput to pre-populate a text area. I have an array of JSON to pre-populate the text area, The text area is populated correctly but when I look at the `<li>`'s created by this plugin it just contain the name of each entry.

How can I get the rest of the information about each entry? In my case like the description, order etc. I need it because I need to insert all these entries into a database.

My jQuery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#text-area").tokenInput("", {
            theme: "facebook",
            prePopulate: [
                          {"id":"04d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 1","description":"Description of Patent Group 1","order":56250000,"is_deleted":false},
                          {"id":"9d4f6e5c-dd73-11e1-bed3-fbfe082dc‌​761","name":"Group 3","description":"Description of Patent Group 3","order":70312500,"is_deleted":false},
                          {"id":"06d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec33‌​5c2","name":"Group 2","description":"Description of Patent Group 2","order":84375000,"is_deleted":false}
                         ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `tokenFormatter` option:

> A function that returns an interpolated HTML string for each token.
>   Use this function with a templating system of your choice, such as
>   jresig microtemplates or mustache.js. Use this when you want to
>   include images or multiline formatted tokens. Quora’s people invite
>   token field that returns avatar tokens is a good example of what can
>   be done this option.

default: `function(item){ return “<li><p>” + item.propertyToSearch + “</p></li>” }` [(demo)](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#formatting).

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#text-area").tokenInput("", {
        theme: "facebook",
        prePopulate: [
                      {"id":"04d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 1","description":"Description of Patent Group 1","order":56250000,"is_deleted":false},
                      {"id":"9d4f6e5c-dd73-11e1-bed3-fbfe082dc‌​761","name":"Group 3","description":"Description of Patent Group 3","order":70312500,"is_deleted":false},
                      {"id":"06d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec33‌​5c2","name":"Group 2","description":"Description of Patent Group 2","order":84375000,"is_deleted":false}
                     ],
        resultsFormatter: function(item){ return "<li>" + "<img src='" + item.url + "' title='" + item.name + "' height='25px' width='25px' />" + "<div style='display: inline-block; padding-left: 10px;'><div class='full_name'>" + item.description + " " + item.order + "</div><div class='email'>" + item.is_deleted + "</div></div></li>" },
        tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.name + " <b style='color: red'>" + item.description + "</b></p></li>" },
    });
});
```

Comment: What is this resultsFormatter used for ?

Comment: tokenFormatter is to format the token that is selected, resultsFormatter is the formatter of the search list

Comment: the ``item`` on that formatter function is a object mapped of the object given as a json. that means you can format your html string any way you want, like this: ``'<li id="'+item.id+'">'+ item.name +'</li>'``

Comment: Done thanks... Now in the form I have one ul and li's for each token what will be the best way to insert each entry in the database?

Comment: One more thing the ul with all the tokens is pre populated but not in the textarea its outside the text area.. why is that ?

Comment: you dont have to do that, the tokenInput plugin fills your field with an array of strings, usually the ids, with this, when the user submits the form, you can get it from the server side.

Comment: if this question answered you, consider accepting it. thank you

Comment: it all depends of your css, the base css of tokenInput should fix it with a little hack

Comment: You mean the input field I created for tokens is filled with array of strings ?

Comment: but my input is hidden and it does not contain any ids

Answer (score 2):

You can use onAdd,onDelete functions to store the selected item description,order into some variable.

```
onAdd:function(item)
{
    alert(item.description);
    alert(item.order);
    //push into array
}
onDelete:function(item)
{
    //remove from array
}
```